# How to use fishshell to add numbers to files

Tags: numbers, fish

I have a very simple mp3 player, and the order it plays audio files are based on the file names, and the rule is there must be a 3-size number in the beginning of file name, such as:

```
001file.mp3
002file.mp3
003file.mp3
```

I want to write a fish shell `sortmp3` to add numbers to the files of a directory. Say directory `myfiles` contains files:

```
aaa.mp3
bbb.mp3
ccc.mp3`
```

When I run `sortmp3 myfiles`, the file names will be changed to:

```
001aaa.mp3
002bbb.mp3
003ccc.mp3
```

But my question is:

1. how to generate some sequential numbers?
2. how to make sure the size of each number is exactly 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write this, which makes no assumptions about how many files there are in a directory:

```
function sortmp3
    set -l files *
    set -l i
    for i in (seq (count $files))
        echo mv $files[$i] (printf "%03d%s" $i $files[$i])
    end
end
```

Remove the "echo" if you like how it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate sequential numbers with the `seq` tool - an external program.

This will only take care of the first part, it won't pad to three characters.

To do that, there's a variety of choices:

```
printf '%s\n' 00(seq 0 99) | rev | cut -c 1-3 | rev
printf '%s\n' 00(seq 0 99) | sed 's/^.*\(...\)$/\1/'
```

The `00(seq 0 99)` part will generate numbers from "1" to "99" with two zeroes prepended - ie. from "001" to "0099". The later parts of the pipeline remove the superfluous zeroes again.

Or with the next fish version, you can use the new `string` tool:

```
string sub -s -3 -- 00(seq 0 99)
```

Comment: Why not just "printf '%03d\n' (seq 0 99)"?

Comment: Because I didn't think of that (I don't use most of printf often)... it's undoubtedly better.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your specific situation you should use the "seq" command to generate sequential numbers or the "math" command to increment a counter. To format the number with a predictable number of leading zeros use the "printf" command:

```
set idx 12
printf '%03d' $idx
```